# Feeding images to Theano throws ShapeMismatch error

Tags: image, theano, predict

I'm trying a really basic example of Theano Logistic Regression model, and after training the net I wanted to test some images to see how they're classified. The code of the training and testing can be found at http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py. In fact the only part I tried to modify is the predict() function as follows:

```
def predict():
    """
    An example of how to load a trained model and use it
    to predict labels.
    """

    # load the saved model
    classifier = cPickle.load(open('best_model.pkl'))

    # compile a predictor function
    predict_model = theano.function(
        inputs=[classifier.input],
        outputs=classifier.y_pred)

    # We can test it on some examples from test test
    #dataset='mnist.pkl.gz'
    #datasets = load_data(dataset)
    #test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]
    #test_set_x = test_set_x.get_value()

    img = Image.open('index.png','r')
    shared_x = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(img,dtype=theano.config.floatX))


    predicted_values = predict_model(shared_x.get_value())
    print ("Predicted values for the first 10 examples in test set:")
    print predicted_values
```

I followed some hints found here http://blog.eduardovalle.com/2015/08/25/input-images-theano/ but apparently I'm having problems since what I get is:

> ValueError: Shape mismatch: x has 28 cols (and 28 rows) but y has 784
>   rows (and 10 cols) Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(x, W)
>   Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64,
>   matrix)] Inputs shapes: [(28, 28), (784, 10)] Inputs strides: [(224,
>   8), (80, 8)] Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']

What is then the correct way to feed images (in my case 28x28) to Theano for prediction?

Answer (score 0):

The model expects *batches* of *flattened* images as input.

The input needs to be a matrix with a row per image. There are 784 columns which is a flattened (or reshaped) version of a 28x28 pixel image (note that 28*28=784).

Instead of

```
img = Image.open('index.png','r')
shared_x = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(img,dtype=theano.config.floatX))
predicted_values = predict_model(shared_x.get_value())
```

Use

```
img = Image.open('index.png','r')
img = numpy.asarray(img, dtype=theano.config.floatX)
img = img.flatten()
x_batch = numpy.expand_dims(img, 0)
predicted_values = predict_model(x_batch)
```

There's no need to use a shared variable since you're just passing the numpy array it contains to the Theano function.